# How to show three columns in a CollectionView using swift4 in all devices

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewflowlayout

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    
    if collectionView == self.collectionViewVideo {

        var collectionViewSize = collectionViewVideo.frame.size
        collectionViewSize.width = collectionViewSize.width/3.0 //Display Three elements in a row.
        return collectionViewSize
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
    }
    
    
}
```

[image: i want to show my collectionview like this]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to take space in account.
Space is your collection view item space

Following is the code has two cells and 20 spaces.
(I am not writing exactly code you need You should do it by your self)

```
extension YourViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: ( self.collectionView.frame.size.width - 60 ) / 2,height:( self.collectionView.frame.size.width - 60 ) / 2)
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
       return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 20, 20)
    }
}
```

Here  `60`  means **SPACE 20** CELL **SPACE 20** CELL **SPACE 20**

Comment: what is insetForSectionAt here sir?

Comment: inset is position where your cell will start. With that you can apply left space to your first cell (20 px) and right space to your right side cell (20 px)

Comment: @GoribDeveloper Try to play with that part and try to understand it. So you don't need next time to put question or need help from internet

Comment: @GoribDeveloper If my answer if helpful if you would not mind could you please mark it as accepted :)