# How to use even spacing between UICollectionViewCell's

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I am trying to display cells of a `UICollectionView` by 2 (110x150) for each row with even spacing for left and right.

However I am trying to work out the spacing by using the `view.frame.width` and the width of the cells, but unfortunately I seem to be doing something wrong.

I have even tried using a width less than 110.0 for the cell and still the collection view only seems to display 1 cellar each row.

**UIViewController**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    let cellWidth : CGFloat = 110.0
    //let screenWidth = screenSize.width

    let numberOfCells = floor(self.view.frame.size.width / cellWidth)
    let edgeInsets = (self.view.frame.size.width - (numberOfCells * cellWidth)) / (numberOfCells + 1)

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, edgeInsets, 0, edgeInsets)
}
```

**Storyboard**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

How can I get the UICollectionView to correctly display two cells side by side with even spacing for left and right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show three columns in a CollectionView using swift4 in all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49795872/how-to-show-three-columns-in-a-collectionview-using-swift4-in-all-devices)

Comment: Does your cell have some sort of shadow? could you give us the code from your cell as well?